# Modem not detected after unplug in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, ubuntu-11.04

I use a modem d-link DWM 152,,
at first be detected, was able to browse. connect the modem still keep fit (I forget if it still connect.), I just unplug it. when i plug it in again, the modem is not detected. How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

try to restart your ubuntu system, and then plug your modem again. You can know your modem had been detected from the autorun of your modem,

Comment: I have tried it but my modem still not detected in system..